# bootstrap 2.3.2 rows not inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I don't understand why this is not inline:

http://jsfiddle.net/dugfresh/dUkz4/

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sun</button></div>
        <div class="span7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Mon</button></div>
        <div class="span7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tue</button></div>
        <div class="span7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Wed</button></div>
        <div class="span7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Thu</button></div>
        <div class="span7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Fri</button></div>
        <div class="span7"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sat</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding how the Bootstrap grid works. `span7` is not for 7 elements in a row, it is for a column that is 7 columns out of 12 wide. So, the way you have written it, only one button will fit in each row. This will also be tough for you since the Bootstrap 12 column grid is not evenly divisible by 7. I don't think you will be able to do what you want within the grid system, I would use TheLittlePig's approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for ??

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/dUkz4/3/

**html** :

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sun</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Mon</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tue</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Wed</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Thu</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Fri</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sat</button>
</div>
```

**doc** :  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonGroups

**UPDATE After comment:**

*You can customize the css for the space :*

```
.btn-group .btn{
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

And make something like

```
<div class="btn-group row-fluid" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary span1">Sun</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary span1">Mon</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary span1">Tue</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary span1">Wed</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary span1">Thu</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary span1">Fri</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary span1">Sat</button>
    </div>
```

Here is the result (responsive) : http://jsfiddle.net/dUkz4/4/

Comment: yes technically that is correct, I want them side by side.  I was looking to allow the grid system to provide spacing between the buttons if possible